# How to reload api call in DART?

Tags: function, api, flutter, dart

I have an method that calls my web api and shows data. When my user presses a button the data should change.

```
 onTap(){

    ///my logic 

    }
```

I want reload api call. So, how could i reload this "onTap"?

Comment: call the api again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the onTap add your call using an object or variable that is in the State of the widget (note the Widget should have a future builder or when tapping the button nothing will happen until the API call completes and effectively changes the object or data):

```
    setState((){
     myReloadingObject;
    })
    ...more code
     onTap(){
       myReloadingObject = await APICall.getmydata()
    }
```